# How to change this Excel formula

Tags: excel

i have this formula to get data to one sheet from another sheet.
But i need to have a formula that will get data from all the sheets between sheet "start" and sheet "end" i have about 80 sheets.

Thank you.

```
= COUNTIF(Huvudlager!$B:$B;"Skruvdragare")
```

Comment: just to be clear, you wish to count the number of times `Skruvdragare` appears in column B for all 80 sheets?

Comment: I would recommend using VBA for this. But I don't know if this is an option for you?

Comment: Yes, count the number of times Skruvdragare appears in column B for all 80 sheets. I dont know VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a clean and easy way to do this all in one cell.

You can however, take advantage of some nifty excel functions to help you with this, namely [GET.WORKBOOK](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/getworkbook-help-in-macro-language-in-excel-2011/a359708d-b5b7-48ba-8d1e-c4114d4642d2) and [INDIRECT](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm).

**Step 1**

Define a [Named Range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) called `SheetList` (or whatever you want) with the following formula:

`=SUBSTITUTE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"["&GET.WORKBOOK(16)&"]","")` *creates an array of worksheet names within the workbook. The substitute function gets rid of the workbook name in the array.*

[image]

**Step 2**

Highlight 80 rows *(since you said you have 80 sheets)* of data on the sheet where you wish to count your data. Then type `=TRANSPOSE(SheetsList)` into the first cell and `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Your sheet list will appear in the 80 rows. *Transpose is needed so the list goes down the rows instead of across columns*.

[image]

**Step 3**

Write the following formula next to each sheet `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A1&"!$B:$B"),"Skruvdragare")` *assumes first sheet name is A1.*

*Edit: You'd be better served to define the row ranges in the COUNTIF formula, since counting every row in a column is very efficient, especially if not all the rows have data. So, use the max number of rows you know will have data across all the sheets, for example: `INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$1:$B$1000")`*

[image]

**Step 4**

Write a formula to sum the counts of each sheet.

Comment: Thank you i will try this. I have somthing simular but it's geting slow.

Comment: @PatrikIdén - another you can do to improve performance is to define the row range in the `COUNTIF` formula. So `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A1&"!$B1:$B1000"),"Skruvdragare"`. Or Adjust the 1000 to the max amount of rows that could possibly have data. Counting the entire column (1048576 rows) is very inefficient, unless indeed all the rows have data - which most likely they do not.

Comment: Thank you, i havent tested this yet, but i will :)