# SUMIF over multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, countif, sumifs

On the main sheet I have a list of names where I have successfully counted the number of times they appear on another twenty 'project' sheets in the cell range C10:C100.

On Cell B5 on every project sheet there is a figure. I want to return the sum of the figures based on how many times a particular name appears from the list on each project sheet.

For example, if `john` is found to appear in range C10:C100 on the first and last project sheets, where the figure for the first is `10,000` and for the last `5,000`, the formula should return value of `15,000`.

The formula I am using is:

```
=SUMIF(project1!$C$10:$C$100,MAIN!B4,project1!$B$5)+SUMIF('project2'!$C$10:$C$100,MAIN!B4,'project2'!$B$5:$D$5)+SUMIF('project3'!$C$10:$C$100,MAIN!B4,'project3'!$B$5:$D$5)+SUMIF('project4'!$C$10:$C$100,MAIN!B4,'project4'!$B$5:$D$5)....and so on.
```

It works well if the name is at the top of the range but if it is further down the list in that range then it returns `0`.

What does it take to fix this?

Comment: if you want to avoid a long formula and sum it up in a bit of a different way, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135482/how-to-change-this-excel-formula/34136039#34136039). It basically lists the worksheet names and then uses `INDIRECT` to write the formulas. Then adds it all up at the end.

Comment: yes @pnuts ... it may, but I still thought it worth exposing the user too, in case it proves helpful. But your reminder is appreciated because it's very worth noting as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIF(Project1!C10:C100,"John")*Project1!B5+
```

`#`

```
+COUNTIF(Project20!C10:C100,"John")*Project20!B5
```

with replacing `#` to suit for the other 18 sheets.

Comment: Yes I missed the value is one cell per sheet.  I like yours but it assumes John is on the list only once.  That may be true, but you could use `IF(COUNTIF(Project1!C10:C100,"John"),Project1!B5,0) + ... +IF(COUNTIF(Project20!C10:C100,"John"),Project20!B5,0)`  and it would not matter if it was once or thirty.

Answer (score 2):

I think this array formula might work for you

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("project"&{1,2,3,4}&"!c10:C100"),"="&MAIN!$B$4),
SUMIF(INDIRECT("project"&{1,2,3,4}&"!B5:D5"),">0")))
```

Change the {1,2,3,4} to an array constant of all your sheet numbers

Comment: That is the value he wants to check is in the range C10:C100 on each of the project sheets. My reading was that if the value in Main!B4 was found ANYWHERE in C10:C100 add the values in B5:D5, otherwise ignore them.

Comment: That's what comes when we have to tease the question out from the formula tried so far :-). As for D5, he missed that for project1 (at least I hope that was a miss).

Comment: @BobPhillips my apologies of the question is confusing, i tried to simplify the question, in doing so i may have confused things a little. the project are not named project1 to project20, but instead they have different names entirely. this explains the difficulty in applying this formula as i am struggling for substituting the projects names into the array. eg, project names are iSMART, Seedcorn 1, Leeds Phd...and so on to around 20 of them.

Comment: No need to apologise mate, I was just having some friendly with pnuts. If the names are not structured, put them in a list in say Main!M1:M20 (or exactly however many there are), and use =SUM(IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&MAIN!$M$1:$M$20&"'!C10:C100"),"="&MAIN!$B$4),
SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&MAIN!$M$1:$M$20&"'!B5:D5"),">0")))